# firebase javascript access denied angularjs maybe bad rule?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to check if an user can register to my app (in this part I'm just checking his username, but btw I want to make sure it won't be possible to register this username even if the user bypasses this checking process). So here are my firebase rules:

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "userPublic": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in with Facebook
        ".read": true,
        "username": {
           ".validate": "!root.child('usernameLookup/'+newData.child('username').val()).exists()"
        }
      }
    },
    "userPrivate": {
      "$uid": {
        "username": {
           ".validate": "!root.child('usernameLookup/'+newData.child('username').val()).exists()"
        },
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in with Facebook
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    },
    "usernameLookup": {
    "$username": {
       // not readable, cannot get a list of usernames!
       // can only write if this username is not already in the db
       ".write": "!data.exists() && !root.child('userPublic/'+auth.uid).exists()"

       // can only write my own uid into this index
       //".validate": "newData.val() === auth.uid"
    }
    }
  }
}
```

And to check in my source code if the user exists:

```
var fb = new Firebase(firebaseURL);
 fb.child('usernameLookup/'+username).set(uid(fb.getAuth().uid), function(err) {
  if( err ) {
      $scope.msg = err+"Username already exists!";
  }
  else
      {
          $scope.msg = "Success";
      }});
```

But I get an access denied error... Please help me! :(

Comment: There's a simulator in the Firebase dashboard that you can use to simulate the operation with. It will tell you exactly why the write is not allowed.

Comment: Without that, we'll need to know the values of `username` `fb.getAuth().uid` and the JSON at `usernameLookup/<username>` to be able to figure this one out.